# Is't true that for a linear transformation $T:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n,~T$ is positive definite $\iff\langle Tx,x\rangle>0~\forall~x\ne 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is't true that for a linear transformation $T:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n,$

1. $T$ is positive definite $\iff\langle Tx,x\rangle>0~\forall~x\ne 0$
2. $T$ is negetive definite $\iff\langle Tx,x\rangle<0~\forall~x\ne 0$

Comment: That is [the definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix).

Comment: As a definition I knew $x^tTx>0~or~<0$

Comment: $x^t T x$ and $\langle Tx, x\rangle$ are different notations for the same thing (at least when the scalars are real).

Comment: @robjohn That link also requires that $T$ is symmetric. Would you call a rotation in $\mathbb{R}^2$ over an angle $\alpha$, $|\alpha| < \pi/2$ positive definite?

Comment: @WimC: I would, but that is just the way I learned them. That article says that "Some authors use more general definitions of 'positive definite' that include some non-symmetric real matrices"

Answer (score 2):

For a square matrix, $T$, $T$ is positive/negative definite if $\langle Tx,x\rangle$ is greater/less than $0$ for all $x\ne0$. $T$ is positive/negative semi-definite if $\langle Tx,x\rangle$ is greater/less than or equal to $0$ for all $x\ne0$.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix) has a lot more about positive definite matrices.

Comment: $T\overset?=M $

Comment: @Berci: indeed. Thanks.